# HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found ... while downloading .dae files on ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

When I try to access a file extension .dae on IIS server... I get this error:

The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

Looks like I am not able to configure something on my IIS Server. Can somebody please direct me to the right places. I am using Visual Express 2012 for web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since directory browsing is disabled for you, only few file types are accessible for the client,
like scripts and images.

In order to allow other file types, try [this link](http://tech-fyi.net/2010/07/17/how-to-enable-iis-7-to-allow-downloading-of-dmg-files-through-the-web-browser/). don't forget to replace the `dmg` with `dae` of course.

Comment: Thanks. I just Found a good solution for this without going to IIS Manager. 

http://blog.syedgakbar.com/2012/08/13/iis-7-and-media-files-404-3-error/

Comment: link is outdated/broken